# Xray diffraction

Tags: diffraction, x-ray-crystallography

why to diffraction, the spacing between the scatterers and the wavelength should be similar in size, For example in xray diffraction to determine crystal structure?
If it not similar what does happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are carrying out X-ray diffraction measurements on a crystal you shine a beam of x-rays at the crystal and you measure the angle that the x-rays are diffracted relative to the original beam. This angle is given by [Bragg's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bragg%27s_law#Bragg_condition):

$$ \sin\theta = \frac{\lambda}{2d} \tag{1} $$

where $d$ is the spacing between planes in the crystal. If the wavelength is greater than $2d$ then the ratio $\lambda/2d$ is greater than one and the equation (1) has no solution. Physically this means we don't see any diffraction from the crystal. This is why there is an upper limit on the wavelength used.

Comment: Thanks if we want to explain without any relation what we can say?

Comment: @FSh I don't think there's a simple way to explain this without understanding the physics involved, and equation (1) comes out of that physics.